# Silverlight calling WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I am new to silverlight, just wanted know if the steps involved in calling the WCF service same in Silverlight as it was in asp or is there any difference.If there is any difference then request you to help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The main things that you needs aware are

1. silverlight support only basichttpbinding
2. you need to have either clientaccesspolicy.xml file or crossdomain.xml in your root folder of wcf host server, then only you can successfully call a webservice from silerlight

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, there is slight difference between asp and silverlight.
In silverlight all service calls are asynchronous, so you have to have an eventhandler for when the async call is completed you get your data.

Just a small e.g

When you call your WCF service from asp, you use

```
proxy_http.FunctionClient fc = new proxy_http.FunctionClient();
        txtDisplay.Text = fc.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtFirst.Text),Convert.ToInt32(txtSecond.Text)).ToString();
```

in case of Silverlight you will use

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        proxy_htt.FunctionClient fc = new proxy_htt.FunctionClient();
        fc.AddCompleted += new EventHandler<proxy_htt.AddCompletedEventArgs>(fc_AddCompleted); 
        fc.AddAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtFirst.Text),Convert.ToInt32(txtSecond.Text));

    }

    void fc_AddCompleted(object sender, proxy_htt.AddCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtResult.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: also the you will have to use either clientaccesspolicy.xml file or crossdomain.xml